# Unable to write unit test case for button click event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on the React JS application. Whenever the user presses Enter I am firing some event as below.

```
dispatchSearch() {
    if (!this.isSearchButtonDisabled()) {
      const searchTerms = { [this.state.searchType]: this.state.searchTerm };
      const searchDbTarget = '';
      const options = {};
      this.props.searchParameters(searchTerms, searchDbTarget, options, this.state.allOpenStoresSearchTerms.selectedOption);
    }
  }
```

The above code works as expected. Below is my unit test case for the above code.

```
 it('should dispatch a keycode when keycode value is set', () => {
    component.setState({ searchTerm: 'some-value', allOpenStoresSearchTerms: {selectedOption: {value: 'true', label: 'Open Stores'}} });
    component.find('SearchInput').props().onKeyPress({ key: 'Enter' });
    expect(dispatchEvent).toBeCalled();
    expect(dispatchEvent).toBeCalledWith({ simsKeycode: 'some-value', allOpenStoresSearchTerms: {selectedOption: {value: 'true', label: 'Open Stores'}} });
  });
```

This unit test case fails and throws below error

> Expected mock function to have been called with:
>         {"allOpenStoresSearchTerms": {"selectedOption": {"label": "Open Stores", "value": "true"}}, "simsKeycode": "some-value"} as argument
>   1, but it was called with {"simsKeycode": "some-value"}.
>         undefined as argument 2, but it was called with "".
>         undefined as argument 3, but it was called with {}.
>         undefined as argument 4, but it was called with {"label": "Open Stores", "value": "true"}.

May I know what I am missing in the above code? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

`setState` method works only when you're mount rendering your component. it doesn't work on shallow render.

Comment: Okay.What I need to change?

Comment: @Niranjan the ideal way to test is to mimic the behavior of your component, via triggering ui actions or user experience. so you could do this or opt to mount render for this test

Comment: `setState` is part of component instance, and instance is complete only when mount rendered.

Comment: Thanks. How can I write proper test case foe this now?

Comment: @Niranjan simplest way is to replace `shallow` with `mount` in your test file. it should be enough for your test to access state. but i cannot really enhance your test method for shallow because i don't know your component logic.